# How to trigger org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException in tests?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I have following error in code, when I save objects in 2 different transactions:

> org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [] with identifier []: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : []

I have been trying to write test for the exception. However, all tests have been passed.

My test:

```
@Slf4j
@Rollback
@Transactional
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "h2"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import(value = {
        StatusService.class
})
class StatusServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RequestRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private StatusService statusService;

    private Request request;
    private final UUID requestUID = UUID.randomUUID();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        request = new Request();
        request.setRequestUID(requestUID);
        repository.save(request);
    }

    @Test
    void updateStatus() {
        Request request1 = repository.findByRequestUID(requestUID);
        Request request2 = repository.findByRequestUID(requestUID);
        statusService.updateStatus(request1, "Done");
        statusService.updateStatus(request2, "In_progress");
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StatusService {
    private final RequestRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void updateStatus(Request request, String status) {
        // Some simple logic
        request.setStatus(status);
        repository.save(request); // The line with error
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Request {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Long id;

    protected UUID requestUID;

    private String status;
    
    // Some additional fields
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Version
    private Integer version;

}
```

Where am I wrong? How to write test for triggering error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) includes `@Transactional` so your test runs in a single transaction.

But for a single transaction the 1st level cache of JPA ensures that you'll get always the same instance for a given class and id.
This means `request1` and `request2` are actually the same instance and there happens only a single flush will can't create an optimistic locking exception.

There are two approaches to create an optimistic locking exception.

1. Actually use two or more transactions. [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) is very useful for this. You could put the loading of the `request1` in a first transaction then load, modify, save, and flush `request2` and then modify, save, and flush `request1`. If you want to have it even closer to what is happen in production you could start two threads doing those operations and by using [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) make sure they proceed in the desired order.
2. Alternatively you should be able to trigger the desired exception by loading a request, modifying its version attribute and flush the transaction. This of course is rather far from what happens in production but as said it should trigger the exception.